# Каким способом образовано слово "заканчивать"?

Tags: словообразование

ЕГЭ говорит, что суффиксальным.
Объясните, пожалуйста, от какого слова оно образовано и как?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Глагол *заканчивать* образован от глагола *закончить* суффиксальным способом (суффикс -ива-)

Answer (score 2):

Да, Лорана и Янна дали правильные ответы. Слово  "заканчивать" образуется суффиксальным способом от слова "закончить"

Чтобы обосновать, надо обратиться к понятию видовой пары. Вот что сказано в с словаре лингвистических терминов.

**"видовая пара**

**Пара, образуемая глаголом несовершенного вида и глаголом совершенного вида при их лексико-семантическом тождестве. Видовые пары образуются:**

1) путем суффиксации, иногда с чередованием гласных или согласных в глагольной основу. Оправдать— оправдывать, переписать — переписывать, закончить — заканчивать, усвоить — усваивать, вырастить — выращивать, выловить — вылавливать, зашить — зашивать, овладеть — овладевать;

2) путем префиксации. Делать — сделать, рисовать — нарисовать, печь — испечь, строить — построить, седлать — оседлать, ремонтировать — отремонтировать, совершенствовать — усовершенствовать;

3) сменой тематических гласных или суффиксов, иногда с чередованием согласных в глагольной основе. Решить — решать, заострить — заострять, встретить — встречать, простить — прощать, пустить — пускать, накопить — накоплять (наряду с накапливать), приготовить — приготовлять (наряду с приготавливать), избегать — избегнуть, привыкать — привыкнуть;

4) изменением места ударения. Насыпать — насыпать, разрезать — разрезать;

5) образованием от разных основ (супплетивные видовые пары). Брать — взять, говорить — сказать, класть — положить, ловить — поймать."

В лингвистике существуют разные точки зрения на глаголы, составляющие видовую пару. Одни лингвисты считают их формами слова, другие - разными словами, третьи- считают, что среди глаголов, составляющих пару, есть как разные слова, так и формы одного слова. 
На сегодняшний день общепринятой считается точка зрения, что это разные слова.  И слова, составляющие видовую пару, часто образуются одно от другого (см. п.1,2 в выдержке из справочника).

А если признать, что это формы одного и того же слова, тогда суффикс -ива- надо считать формообразующим и словообразовательная цепочка будет иной. Но словари и учебные издания отражают точку зрения другую (глаголы разного вида - разные слова).

Comment: А почему не наоборот: закончить от заканчивать?

Answer (score 1):

Словообразовательный разбор начинают с определения лексического значения слова. На экзамене словарей нет, поэтому придётся определять "своими словами".
"Заканчивать" -- то же самое, что и "закончить".Только процесс ещё не завершён,поэтому глагол "заканчивать" несовершенного вида.
Строим цепочку: закончить--и-- + ива = заканчивать. К основе прибавили суффикс, получили суффиксальный способ.

Answer (score 0):

Если мы имеем видовую пару глаголов, то один глагол образуется от другого. 
 Закончить (сов.) - заканчивать (несов.) - это регулярное образование в языке с характерными особенностями:  чередование О/А в корне и отсечение глагольного суффикса.

Чтобы не ошибиться при определении главного (мотивирующего) слова для видовой пары, берете любой толковый словарь, и там эта информация всегда имеется, например у Ожегова: ЗАКОНЧИТЬ, сов.,  что. Кончить (в  1 и  2 знач. и  окончить. 3акончить спор. 3акончить работу. || несов. заканчивать.

Answer (score -2):

Заканчивать. Вот его строение: За - канч -ива- ть (несовершенный вид)
за-кон-чить (совершенный вид) происходит чередование А-О в корне. Образовано слово от кончить - при помощи приставки ЗА- и суффикса -ИВА- (ТЬ -окончание)

Comment: И мне кажется, что глагол сов. вида закончить образованн от глагола сов вида кончить (приставочным способом),  а глагол несов. вида закнчивать образован от глагола несов. вида кончать. Почему-то мне это кажется логичным. 
хотелось бы увидеть ответ Людмилы или Ларf.  Хотя, думаю, они согласятся с вариантом ЕГЭ, но и сумеют доказать его правильность.